# Determine $\dim(\{ z \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}(A):z'=-z \})$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 6 \\ 0 & -1 & -8 \\ 0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix} \in Mat_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(A)$ denote the vector space of solutions to the system of linear ODE $x'=Ax$.

Consider the following subspace $V=\{ z \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}(A):z'=-z \}$.

Determine $\dim(V)$.

---

**My idea:**

First of all we know that $\dim(\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(A))=3$ since we have a result stating:

*"For a matrix $A \in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ then $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear isomorphism and $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(A)$ is a vector space of dimension $n$."*

Now I was thinking that we can write $z'=-z=(-1)Iz$ such that the solutions of this ODE can be denoted as $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(I)$, where $I \in Mat_1(\mathbb{R})$. Then we can use the result above and conclude that $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(I) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a linear isomorphism and $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(I)$ is a vector space of dimension $1$.

**Is this correct or have I made a mistake? Thanks in advance!**

Comment: in that subspace $V$, you're essentially looking at an equation of the form $Ax = -x$. It is readily verifiable that $-1$ is an eigenvalue with the given $A$, and produces an eigenbasis of dimension 1. This verifies the result.

Comment: You said that you want a *subspace* of $L(A)$. It seems like the condition that another set of ODE's has to be satisfied at the same time got lost somewhere along the way...

Comment: You made a mistake when saying that $I\in Mat_1(\mathbb{R})$. The elements of $V$ are elements of $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(A)$, which are $3$-vectors of functions. So the condition $z'=-z$ is still an equation between $3$-vectors. You need the identity matrix of size $3$ to write it.

Comment: Note that you can compute $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(I)$ directly. They are the functions $z=e^{-t}v$ where $v$ is a constant $3$-vector. Then of those impose the condition that $z'=Az$. this gives $-e^{-t}v=z'=A(e^{-t}v)=e^{-t}Av$. This is equivalent to $v=Av$, from where you can find the dimension of the space of $v$.

Comment: DaveNine, so you are saying that if $E_A(-1)$ is the eigenspace for $\lambda=-1$ then $V=E_A(-1)$?

Comment: @CruZ that’s precisely what it means to be a basis of a substance: you’re able to generate any element efficiently with linear combinations of those elements. In this case there is just one vector in that span.